# How to keep same url for diffrent store in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.8

i am currently working on Magento 1.9. I have setup to two website in my Magento now i want to keep same product url for both store :-

```
Store 1 :- www.mydomain.com/
store 2 :- www.mydomain.com/store2/
```

Now it's possible to keep product url same like:-

```
www.mydomain.com/nokia
and for www.mydomain.com/store2/
www.mydomain.com/nokia
```

Please suggest if it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in more details why exactly do you want such behavior? From first view this is not possible, but maybe if you explain the requirements you can get some constructive suggestions.

Comment: I have a product like nokia-3315 and in my Magento now i am getting two url for single product i want to keep single url : current i have :- www.mysite.com/nokia-3315 and www.mysite.com/store2/nokia-3315

Comment: Are you trying to setup two instances for load balancing? To me it looks like that. In such case, those Magento websites should reside on separate machines and you should have a load balancer in front (Nginx is a good choice).